# VZ Exif - has someone used this on forums?

Tags: image, forum, attachment

I have been searching for solution to show EXIF infos on images on my forums. I found so far only VZ Exif that is EE2-ready, but didnt manage to make it work with forums, even that i run my forums via regular template.

So, can someone guide me, or give a helping hand, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, because ExpressionEngine Forum Module does not give out the actual attachment location in url, you can not use this within Forums, even if they run via regular templates.

In order to make the add-on work in forums, you have to find out a way to get the actual path and name for attached image, something like /forum_attacments/testimage.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The forums module is a very different beast. If you're using regular EE templates however then it should work. If you're not seeing any EXIF data output using VZ Exif then make sure you have [PHP EXIF extension](http://php.net/manual/de/book.exif.php) installed. Run phpinfo() and search for 'exif'.

Also ensure that EXIF data is actually attached to your image files. Run a standard test in regular templates first to be sure.